# One Image Below another one in CSS

Tags: css, image

How do I make one image appear under another image using CSS? for example I am trying to achieve something like

```
[image 1.jpg]
[image 2.jpg]
```

I am a beginner in CSS

Here is my code, why doesn't it work?:

```
<img { display: block; width: 246px; height: 203px; } title="Chocolate Moltres Cake Recipe" src="print_files/chocolatecake.jpg" alt="Chocolate Moltres Cake Recipe" border="0">
<img { display: block; width: 246px }title="Moltres" src="i.imgur.com/simHG.jpg"; alt="Moltres" border="0">
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Beginners will not go far without effort.

Answer (score 9):

Just use this simple CSS rule:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

So, in your case:

```
<img style="display: block;" src="xxx.jpg" alt="" />
```

They will display under each other.

But, since XHTML 1.0, inline CSS rules (`style=""`) is no longer valid. You **SHOULD** use a external CSS file linked to your HTML.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/MhRcD/)

I suggest you read the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) pages about CSS. I've learned from here.

Comment: <img {
    display: block;
    width: 246px;
    height: 203px;    
} title="Chocolate Moltres Cake Recipe" src="print_files/chocolatecake.jpg" alt="Chocolate Moltres Cake Recipe" border="0"><img {
    display: block;
    width: 246px    
}title="Moltres" src="http://i.imgur.com/simHG.jpg" alt="Moltres" border="0">

Comment: PUT YOUR THE CSS IN A `STYLE=""` ATTRIBUTE!!!! LIKE THAT: `<img style="display: block; width: 246px; height: 203px;" src="" alt="" border="0" />`!!!!!